# How do tag teams work?

Tags: spiderman-unlimited

In Spider-Man Unlimited, how do tag teams work? I just unlocked them after finishing issue 1, but it's really unclear to me what they do. I just add some Spideys to my team, but, as far as I can tell, I can only use Spidey #1.

I would expect to be able to tag them in and out, or to continue with my backup when one Spider-Man bites it, but I didn't get any explanation from the in-game tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too was hoping they worked like lives, they don't. Basically, all the Spider-men in your team gain experience from each run, and if you choose to revive using ISO-8, a different Spider-Man will continue the run, using its own bonus ability/abilities. Also, the bonus multipliers for each Spider-man in the team is accumulated.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Manek already said, the bonus multiplier for score will also get summed across all spideys in the tag team.